# System.Timer event stopped firing

Tags: c#, timer

I have a class called Scheduler which runs two timers triggering events at different intervals.

The parent project is constantly running and both events have been triggering fine for around two weeks, however this morning I noticed my informational log which logs that the events have run successfully has logged no events since 9am.

My timers are started here:

```
public void Start()
{

        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += CheckNotifications;

        _matchedTimer.Interval = 600000;
        _matchedTimer.Elapsed += CheckMessages;


        _timer.Start();
        _matchedTimer.Start();
}
```

And I don't stop my timers at any point in my event methods:

What could be the reasons for this stopping all of a sudden?

The strange thing in this instance is that this project is running as a service on an VM running windows server, and restarting the service hasn't started the timer again either. What could be broken that isn't fixed by restarting the program?

Comment: Maybe something's wrong in what the timer method action! Do you log action as the first activity? Did you look at Windows log?

Comment: Are you sure that the timers not firing is the problem or it the problem that the logging is failing?

Comment: i think what is there in the event handler can put more details. above code doesn't have any prob

Comment: @EmanueleGreco I do log as the first action in the method just after instantiating a few objects of other classes. I haven't checked the windows log yet. I do access a DbContext from my MVC site which could potentially be the issue as I have run migrations on this and the project is deployed on this server. But I don't get why the service would not simply run and fail.

Comment: @shf301 I have tested the system to check this and the methods have stopped running. The most confusing thing to me is why a restart wouldn't solve this problem? If it was an exception which crashed the service surely a restart would solve this?

Comment: @sumeetkumar Will post the code with commented out bits as it's a very long winded chunk of code.